# R long to wide with time variable as rownames

Tags: r

I would like to transfer a dataset from long to wide with the time variable as the new rownames and the identification variable as the new colnames. The dataset looks like:

`df <- data.frame(year = c(2007,2008,2007),
                 comp = c("A","A","B"),
                 value = c(4,5,9))
df`

The dataset sometimes does not include values for all companies at all time. These values are just missing and do not appear as NA in the dataset. However, I would like to have them in the result as NA

I would like to get it in a format like:

`df1 <- matrix(data = c(4,5,9,NA),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
colnames(df1) <- c("A","B")
rownames(df1) <- c(2007,2008)
df1`

I tried the reshape function. However, it does not give out the data in my preferred format. Does somebody know a function that gives me my preferred format?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(year = c(2007,2008,2007),
           comp = c("A","A","B"),
           value = c(4,5,9)) %>% 
  spread(comp, value)
```